# Search Formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to know how to identify a particular character in a column in Excel is used.
I am using this formula :

```
=IF((CODE(A1)=63),"YES","NO")
```

but only checks the first character and the second character and then not be checked.
Please guide me.

Comment: Please give some examples with expected results.

Comment: Please provide a better description.

Comment: @pnuts , 
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,CODE(A1)=63)), "Yes", "No")

but same above formula

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
={SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND(CHAR(63),A1:A999)),0,1))>0}
```

This is a matrix formula, enter without braces but terminate with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Don't put this into column A.

Comment: Unless the OP actually has data extending to beyond row one million, an array formula which references an entire column (A:A) is not at all a good idea.

Comment: @XORLX: true, but easily adaptable for the OP. I've changed the formula anyway to account for your advice. OP simply didn't specify any limits - the task is to find out if a special character is used anywhere in a cell of a particular column, as far as I've understood the question.

Comment: It appears that you are referencing entire columns still? And the OP might not be aware of how bad an idea it is unless we tell them.

Comment: @XORLX: the formula is not referencing one or more entire columns, just a single range within one column. Maybe I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It was previously (A:A). You've changed it since I posted that comment.